PanicException: assertion `left == right` failed in Write_Parquet Polars
I have a problem when I try to use write_parquet('name.parquet', compression='gzip', compression_level=10) from Polars. I have been trying different solutions but nothing isn't works.   I get the following error.
I'm trying to use rechunk() but isn't working. Also, I tried changing the compression and compression_level but always get the same error.

 
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 new_df.rechunk().write_parquet('name.parquet', compression='gzip', compression_level=10)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py:3499, in DataFrame.write_parquet(self, file, compression, compression_level, statistics, row_group_size, data_page_si

ze, use_pyarrow, pyarrow_options)
   3492         pa.parquet.write_table(
   3493             table=tbl,
   3494             where=file,
   3495             **(pyarrow_options or {}),
   3496         )
   3498 else:
-> 3499     self._df.write_parquet(
   3500         file,
   3501         compression,
   3502         compression_level,
   3503         statistics,
   3504         row_group_size,
   3505         data_page_size,
   3506     )

PanicException: assertion `left == right` failed
  left: -2
 right: 0


Any ideas? Thank you so much!

If you can create a reproducible example of new_df you should file it as a bug on github. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/
